# Extracting a numbers from filenames

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bunch of files that all have a name and a serial number and an extension. I want to extract this serial number and extension. They look like this:

```
photo-123.jpg
photo-456.png
photo-789.bmp
```

etc.

I want to run a bash script to extract these serial numbers and place them in a file in this way:

```
123
456
789
```

etc.

Note that not all the photos have the same extension (`bmp`, `png`, `jpg`) but they all start with `photo-`.

Comment: I want you to make my script for me!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Is this sarcasm or do you really want the script?

Comment: maybe sarcasm... have you tried anything before asking your question?

Comment: why is this tagged `batch-file`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [parameter substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ ls
photo-123.jpg  photo-456.png  photo-7832525239.bmp  photo-789.bmp

$ for file in *; do 
    [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue
    [[ $file == "num.log" ]] && continue
    file=${file%.*} && echo "${file#*-}" 
done > num.log

$ ls
num.log  photo-123.jpg  photo-456.png  photo-7832525239.bmp  photo-789.bmp

$ cat num.log 
123
456
7832525239
789
```

`${parameter#word}` removes the **shortest** match from the **start** and `${parameter##word}` removes the **longest** match from the **start**. `${parameter%word}` on the contrary will remove **shortest** match from the **end** and `${parameter%%word}` will remove **longest** match from the **end**.

Alternatively, you can read about [nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob) instead of checking for existence of file in event there are no files in the directory. (Thanks [Adrian Frühwirth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612462/adrian-fruhwirth) for great feedback)

Comment: The quotes around `f=${file%.*}` are not needed as word splitting/globbing does not occur in non-array assignments and you might want to throw in a note about `nullglob` or an `[ -f "${file}" ] || continue` as safety net. Also, if you add the prefix as part of the glob (`for file in photo-*`) you don't need to check for the file you are writing to as `$file` would not expand to that file. But other than that this is it, +1. EDIT: Well, +1 when I am allowed to vote again.

Comment: You could use [parameter expansion on arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) to avoid the loop: `set -- *; set -- "${@%.*}"; set -- "${@#*-}"; printf "%s\n" "$@"`

Comment: @JS웃 If I want to specify a specific folder ad directory for num.log, should I edit the places where it appears or something else?

Comment: @user3084450 that's a good question. For writing the log file to specific directory just modify the `>num.log` to `/path/to/save/num.log` And you can remove the statement where we check if file is num.log since we no longer have the log file under the same location as your pictures.

Answer (score 2):

Using BASH regex:

```
f='photo-123.jpg'
[[ "$f" =~ -([0-9]+)\. ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
123
```

To run it against all the matching files:

```
for f in *-[0-9]*.*; do
   [[ "$f" =~ -([0-9]+)\. ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

Comment: I've used ```photo-123.jpg``` as an example, the serial number has a huge range of possibilities(from 1 digit to 7)

Comment: This regex `[0-9]+` will match 1 or more digits. It can be any # of digits.

Comment: If it doesn't work for some reason then provide some examples of those filenames that are giving problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just want to keep all of the numbers and you're using bash, here are a couple of things which you may find useful:

```
danny@machine:~$ file=abc123def.jpg
danny@machine:~$ echo ${file//[^0123456789]/}
123
danny@machine:~$ echo ${file##*.}
jpg
danny@machine:~$ echo ${file//[^0123456789]/}.${file##*.}
123.jpg
```

You should be able to write your script based on that.  Or, just remove the leading "photo-" from $name by using

```
newname=$(name#photo-}
```

Those and several others are explained in the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) man page's [Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) section.

Comment: I want to write the numbers to a file

Comment: The `>` and `>>` operators are also documented in the man page, or possibly in the book your homework assignment came from. :)

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe with two consecutive awk calls:

```
ls -1 | awk -F- '{print $2}' | awk -F. '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
ls -l | awk {'print $9'} | grep -o -E '[0-9]*'
```

in the directory where the files reside?